# code coverage is low ,plz help me any one

Tags: unit-test

```
public class adjustmentController {
    @AuraEnabled public static String thisQuarterLabelval{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public static String secodQuarterLabelval{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public static String thirdQuarterLabelval{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public static String fourthQuarterLabelval{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static wrapperAdjustmentLabel fetchLabels(String SelectedUserId){
        system.debug('SelectedUserId>>>>'+SelectedUserId);
        Id LoggedinUserId=UserInfo.getUserId();
        Boolean isThisManager,Enablegrid1,Enablegrid2,Enablegrid3,Enablegrid4;
        Set<Id> UserIdSet= new Set<Id>();
        String year = String.valueof(system.today().year());
        String month = String.valueof(system.now().format('M'));
        Integer weekcal = integer.valueof(system.now().format('W'));
        List<User> UserList = new List<User>();
        
        UserList=[Select Id, Name, UserRoleId, UserRole.Name, ManagerId, Manager.Name, IsActive from User where IsActive = true and ManagerId != null and ManagerId =:LoggedinUserId];
        system.debug('UserList>>>>'+UserList);
        for(User u:UserList){
            UserIdSet.add(u.Id);
        }
        if(UserIdSet.contains(SelectedUserId)){
            isThisManager=true;
        }else{
            isThisManager=false;
        }
        
        wrapperAdjustmentLabel wrap =new wrapperAdjustmentLabel();
        List<Period> currentFiscalYear = [SELECT Id, FiscalYearSettingsId, FiscalYearSettings.Name, StartDate, EndDate, IsForecastPeriod, Number, FullyQualifiedLabel FROM Period Where type = 'Quarter' AND StartDate = THIS_FISCAL_YEAR];
        
        system.debug('currentFiscalYear>>>>>'+currentFiscalYear[0].StartDate);
        wrap.thisQuarterLabel= currentFiscalYear[0].FullyQualifiedLabel.right(4)+'-Q1';
        wrap.secodQuarterLabel= currentFiscalYear[1].FullyQualifiedLabel.right(4)+'-Q2';
        wrap.thirdQuarterLabel= currentFiscalYear[2].FullyQualifiedLabel.right(4)+'-Q3';
        wrap.fourthQuarterLabel= currentFiscalYear[3].FullyQualifiedLabel.right(4)+'-Q4';
        
        Integer QStartdat = currentFiscalYear[0].StartDate.month();
        Integer QEndDate = currentFiscalYear[0].EndDate.month();
        Integer Currentmonth = Integer.valueOf(month);
        if(QStartdat>=Currentmonth || QEndDate>=Currentmonth){  Enablegrid1=false;
        }else{
            system.debug('Enablegrid1 true');
            Enablegrid1=true;
        }
        if(currentFiscalYear[1].StartDate.month() >= Currentmonth || currentFiscalYear[1].EndDate.month() >= Currentmonth){  Enablegrid2=false;
        }else{
            system.debug('Enablegrid2 true');
            Enablegrid2=true;
        }
        if(currentFiscalYear[2].StartDate.month() >= Currentmonth || currentFiscalYear[2].EndDate.month() >= Currentmonth){
            system.debug('Enablegrid3 false');
            Enablegrid3=false;
        }else{
            system.debug('Enablegrid3 true');
            Enablegrid3=true;
        }
        if(currentFiscalYear[3].StartDate.month() >= Currentmonth || currentFiscalYear[3].EndDate.month() >= Currentmonth){
            system.debug('Enablegrid4 false');
            Enablegrid4=false;
        }else{
            system.debug('Enablegrid4 true');
            Enablegrid4=true;
        }
        
        
        system.debug('QStartdat>>>>'+QStartdat);
        system.debug('QEndDate>>>>'+QEndDate);
        system.debug('Currentmonth>>>>'+Currentmonth);
        
        wrap.isEnablegrid1=Enablegrid1;
        wrap.isEnablegrid2=Enablegrid2;
        wrap.isEnablegrid3=Enablegrid3;
        wrap.isEnablegrid4=Enablegrid4;
        wrap.isManager=isThisManager;
        thisQuarterLabelval=currentFiscalYear[0].FullyQualifiedLabel;
        secodQuarterLabelval=currentFiscalYear[1].FullyQualifiedLabel;
        thirdQuarterLabelval=currentFiscalYear[2].FullyQualifiedLabel;
        fourthQuarterLabelval=currentFiscalYear[3].FullyQualifiedLabel;
        
        List<User_SO__c> UserSoList=[select id,Year__c,Month__c,User__c,Week_1_Adjustment__c,Week_2_Adjustment__c,Week_3_Adjustment__c,Week_4_Adjustment__c,Week_5_Adjustment__c,Week_6_Adjustment__c from User_SO__c where Month__c=:month and Year__c=:year and User__c=:SelectedUserId and RecordType.Name='User'];
        system.debug('UserSoList>>>'+ UserSoList);
        
        String Examplefield;
        FcstJSONClass fcstParentAccWrapObj;
        Date currentdate = Date.today(); 
        FCSTUtil util = new FCSTUtil();
        Integer currentweek = util.currentWeekOfMonth(currentdate);
        String currentmonthweek = String.valueOf(currentweek);
        //system.debug('currentmonthweek>>> '+currentmonthweek);
        
        if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && currentmonthweek == '1'){ Examplefield = UserSoList[0].Week_1_Adjustment__c;  
        } else if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && currentmonthweek == '2'){ Examplefield = UserSoList[0].Week_2_Adjustment__c;  
        } else if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && currentmonthweek == '3'){  Examplefield = UserSoList[0].Week_3_Adjustment__c;  
        } else if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && currentmonthweek == '4'){  Examplefield = UserSoList[0].Week_4_Adjustment__c;  
        } else if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && currentmonthweek == '5'){  Examplefield = UserSoList[0].Week_5_Adjustment__c;  
        } else if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && currentmonthweek == '6'){ Examplefield = UserSoList[0].Week_6_Adjustment__c;  
        }
        
        if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && Examplefield != null){ fcstParentAccWrapObj=(FcstJSONClass) System.JSON.deserialize(Examplefield, FcstJSONClass.class);
            
            //system.debug('fcstParentAccWrapObj>>>>>'+fcstParentAccWrapObj);
            //system.debug('fcstParentAccWrapObjQuarter>>>>>'+fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter);
            //system.debug('Q1>>>>>'+fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q1);
            // system.debug('fcstParentAccWrapObjQuarter>>>>>'+fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0]);
            
            if(fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q1!=null){
                wrap.thisQuarterValue=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q1;
            }
            if(fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q2!=null){
                wrap.secodQuarterValue=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q2;
            }
            if(fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q3!=null){
                wrap.thirdQuarterValue=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q3;
            }
            if(fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q4!=null){
                wrap.fourthQuarterValue=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q4;
            }
        }
        
        system.debug('wrap>>>'+wrap);
        return wrap;
        
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void savedata(wrapperAdjustment wrapper1,String SelectedUserId){
        system.debug('SelectedUserId>>>>>'+SelectedUserId);
       
        String Usermass='Success';
        Id LoggedinUserId=UserInfo.getUserId();
        Set<Id> UserIdSet= new Set<Id>();
        
        List<User> UserList=[Select Id, Name, UserRoleId, UserRole.Name, ManagerId, Manager.Name, IsActive from User where IsActive = true and ManagerId != null and ManagerId =:LoggedinUserId];
        
        for(User u:UserList){
            UserIdSet.add(u.Id);
        }
        
        String year = String.valueof(system.today().year());
        String month = String.valueof(system.now().format('M'));
        Integer weekcal = integer.valueof(system.now().format('W'));
        String Week1_Adjustment,Week2_Adjustment,Week3_Adjustment,Week4_Adjustment,Week5_Adjustment,Week6_Adjustment;
        fetchLabels(SelectedUserId);
        system.debug('SelectedUserId>>>>>'+SelectedUserId);
        system.debug('UserIdSet>>>>>'+UserIdSet);
        if(UserIdSet.contains(SelectedUserId)){
            
            String StartFiscalYear=thisQuarterLabelval.right(4)+'-Q1';
            String EndFiscalYear=fourthQuarterLabelval.right(4)+'-Q4';
            // system.debug('StartFiscalYear>>>>'+StartFiscalYear);
            // system.debug('EndFiscalYear>>>>'+EndFiscalYear);
            
            Usermass='Success';
             system.debug('RecordType.Name>>>'+RecordType.Name);
             system.debug('month>>>'+month);
            system.debug('SelectedUserId>>>'+SelectedUserId);
             system.debug('year>>>'+year);
             if(Test.isRunningTest()){
            month='1';
        }
             system.debug('UserSo----'+[select id,Year__c,Month__c from User_SO__c where User__c=:SelectedUserId]);
            
            List<User_SO__c> UserSoList=[select id,Year__c,Month__c,User__c,Week_1_Adjustment__c,Week_2_Adjustment__c,Week_3_Adjustment__c,Week_4_Adjustment__c,Week_5_Adjustment__c,Week_6_Adjustment__c from User_SO__c where Month__c=:month and Year__c=:year and User__c=:SelectedUserId and RecordType.Name='User'];
            system.debug('UserSoList>>>'+UserSoList);
            
            String QuarterQ1='0',QuarterQ2='0',QuarterQ3='0',QuarterQ4='0';
            String Examplefield;
            FcstJSONClass fcstParentAccWrapObj;
            
            Date currentdate = Date.today(); 
            FCSTUtil util = new FCSTUtil();
            Integer currentweek = util.currentWeekOfMonth(currentdate);
            String currentmonthweek = String.valueOf(currentweek);
            
            if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && currentmonthweek == '1'){ Examplefield = UserSoList[0].Week_1_Adjustment__c;  
            } else if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && currentmonthweek == '2'){ Examplefield = UserSoList[0].Week_2_Adjustment__c;  
            } else if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && currentmonthweek == '3'){ Examplefield = UserSoList[0].Week_3_Adjustment__c;  
            } else if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && currentmonthweek == '4'){ Examplefield = UserSoList[0].Week_4_Adjustment__c;  
            } else if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && currentmonthweek == '5'){ Examplefield = UserSoList[0].Week_5_Adjustment__c;  
            } else if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && currentmonthweek == '6'){ Examplefield = UserSoList[0].Week_6_Adjustment__c;  
            }
            
            if(!UserSoList.isEmpty() && Examplefield != null){ fcstParentAccWrapObj=(FcstJSONClass) System.JSON.deserialize(Examplefield, FcstJSONClass.class);
                
                if(fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q1!=null){
                    QuarterQ1=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q1;
                }
                if(fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q2!=null){
                    QuarterQ2=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q2;
                }
                if(fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q3!=null){
                    QuarterQ3=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q3;
                }
                if(fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q4!=null){
                    QuarterQ4=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q4;
                }
            }
            
            JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(false);
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField('Fiscal_Year', StartFiscalYear +' to '+ EndFiscalYear);
            gen.writeStringField('Year', Year);
            gen.writeStringField('Month', Month);
            gen.writeStringField('Week', currentmonthweek);
            gen.writeStringField('UserId', SelectedUserId);
            gen.writeFieldName('Quarter');
            gen.writeStartArray();
            gen.writeStartObject();
            
            if(wrapper1.thisQuarter!=null){ gen.writeStringField('Q1',String.valueof(wrapper1.thisQuarter) );
            }else{
                gen.writeStringField('Q1',QuarterQ1 );
            }
            
            if(wrapper1.secodQuarter!=null){ gen.writeStringField('Q2',String.valueof(wrapper1.secodQuarter) );
            }else{
                gen.writeStringField('Q2',QuarterQ2 );
            }
            
            if(wrapper1.thirdQuarter!=null){ gen.writeStringField('Q3',String.valueof(wrapper1.thirdQuarter) );
            }else{
                gen.writeStringField('Q3',QuarterQ3);
            }
            
            if(wrapper1.fourthQuarter!=null){ gen.writeStringField('Q4',String.valueof(wrapper1.fourthQuarter) );
            }else{
                gen.writeStringField('Q4',QuarterQ4);
            }
            
            gen.writeEndObject();
            gen.writeEndArray();
            gen.writeEndObject();
            String Json=gen.getAsString();
            
            system.debug('json>>>>'+json);
            Week3_Adjustment = json ;
            
            if(UserSoList.size()>0)
            { 
                for(User_SO__c SO:UserSoList){
                    if(currentweek==1){
                        SO.Week_1_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;
                        SO.Week_2_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;
                        SO.Week_3_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;
                        SO.Week_4_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;  
                        SO.Week_5_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;   
                        SO.Week_6_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;
                        /*if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                          currentweek=2;
                         } */
                    }
                    else if(currentweek==2){
                        
                        SO.Week_2_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;
                        SO.Week_3_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;
                        SO.Week_4_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;  
                        SO.Week_5_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;   
                        SO.Week_6_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;
                        
                    }
                    else if(currentweek==3){
                        
                        SO.Week_3_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;
                        SO.Week_4_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;  
                        SO.Week_5_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;   
                        SO.Week_6_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;
                        
                    }
                    else if(currentweek==4){ SO.Week_4_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;  SO.Week_5_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;   
                        SO.Week_6_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;
                        
                    }
                    else if(currentweek==5){ SO.Week_5_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ; SO.Week_6_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;
                        
                    }
                    else if(currentweek==6){ SO.Week_6_Adjustment__c=Week3_Adjustment ;
                        
                    }
                    system.debug('currentweek>>>'+currentweek);
                    system.debug('SO>>>>>'+SO);
                    update SO;
                    
                }
                
                
            }
        } else {
            Usermass='You are not authorised Person'; 
            system.debug('Usermass>>>'+Usermass);
        }
    }
}
```

test class::

```
@isTest
public class Test_adjustmentController {
    
    static testmethod void adjustmentControllerTest(){
        FCST_Trigger_Setting__c setting = new FCST_Trigger_Setting__c();
        setting.Name = 'FCSTUserSOTrigger';
        setting.FCST_Active__c = true;
        insert setting;
        
        User thisUser = [ select Id, Name,UserRole.Name, UserRoleId from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
        System.runAs(thisUser){
            FcstQuotaWrapper paramObj = new FcstQuotaWrapper();
            FcstQuotaWrapper.AllQuotaData paramObj1 = new FcstQuotaWrapper.AllQuotaData();
            
            UserRole r = new UserRole(DeveloperName = 'MyCustomRole', Name = 'My Role' );
            insert r;
            
            UserRole r1 = new UserRole(DeveloperName = 'MyCustomRole1', Name = 'My Role1', ParentRoleId = r.id );
            insert r1;
            
            
            
            Profile profileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User' LIMIT 1];
            
            User u = new User(LastName = 'LIVESTON',
                              FirstName='JASON',
                              Alias = 'jliv',
                              Email = 'puser000@amamama.com',
                              Username = 'puser000@amamama.com' + System.currentTimeMillis(),
                              ProfileId = profileId.id,
                              TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT',
                              LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                              EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                              LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                              isActive = True,
                              ManagerId  = thisUser.id,
                              UserRoleId = r1.Id
                             );
            insert u;
            
            List<RecordType> rtypes = [Select Name, Id From RecordType where Name = 'User' ];
            
            System.debug('rtypes>>>>'  + rtypes.size());    
            
            Set<Id> UserIdSet= new Set<Id>();
            UserIdSet.add(thisUser.id);
            //insert UserIdSet;
             String year = String.valueof(system.today().year());
             String month = String.valueof(system.now().format('M'));
            Datetime currentdate = Datetime.now(); 
            String currentmonthweek = currentdate.format('W');
            
            List<User_SO__c>  objs1 = new List<User_SO__c>();
            User_SO__c  obj  = new User_SO__c();
            obj.Year__c  =  year;
            obj.Month__c  = month;
            obj.User__c  = u.id;
            obj.Week_1_Adjustment__c =  '{"Fiscal_Year":"2022-Q1 to 2023-Q4","Year":"2022","Month":"8","Week":"1","UserId":"0055f000008L3nlAAC","Quarter":[{"Q1":"500","Q2":"600","Q3":"700","Q4":"800"}]}';
            obj.Week_2_Adjustment__c =  '{"Fiscal_Year":"2022-Q1 to 2023-Q4","Year":"2022","Month":"8","Week":"2","UserId":"0055f000008L3nlAAC","Quarter":[{"Q1":"500","Q2":"600","Q3":"700","Q4":"800"}]}';
            obj.Week_3_Adjustment__c =   '{"Fiscal_Year":"2022-Q1 to 2023-Q4","Year":"2022","Month":"8","Week":"3","UserId":"0055f000008L3nlAAC","Quarter":[{"Q1":"500","Q2":"600","Q3":"700","Q4":"800"}]}';
            obj.Week_4_Adjustment__c =   '{"Fiscal_Year":"2022-Q1 to 2023-Q4","Year":"2022","Month":"8","Week":"4","UserId":"0055f000008L3nlAAC","Quarter":[{"Q1":"500","Q2":"600","Q3":"700","Q4":"800"}]}';
            obj.Week_5_Adjustment__c =  '{"Fiscal_Year":"2022-Q1 to 2023-Q4","Year":"2022","Month":"8","Week":"5","UserId":"0055f000008L3nlAAC","Quarter":[{"Q1":"500","Q2":"600","Q3":"700","Q4":"800"}]}';
            obj.Week_6_Adjustment__c =  '{"Fiscal_Year":"2022-Q1 to 2023-Q4","Year":"2022","Month":"8","Week":"6","UserId":"0055f000008L3nlAAC","Quarter":[{"Q1":"500","Q2":"600","Q3":"700","Q4":"800"}]}';
            obj.RecordTypeId  = rtypes[0].id;
            objs1.add(obj);
            
            insert objs1;
            
            wrapperAdjustment objs = new wrapperAdjustment();
            FcstJSONClass.cls_Quarter osj  = new FcstJSONClass.cls_Quarter();
            System.assertEquals(null, objs.thisQuarter);
            System.assertEquals(null, objs.secodQuarter);
            System.assertEquals(null, objs.thirdQuarter);
            System.assertEquals(null, objs.fourthQuarter);
            
            wrapperAdjustmentLabel ons  = new wrapperAdjustmentLabel();
            System.assertEquals(null, ons.thisQuarterValue);
            System.assertEquals(null, ons.secodQuarterValue);
            System.assertEquals(null, ons.thirdQuarterValue);
            System.assertEquals(null, ons.fourthQuarterValue);
            
            //String month = String.valueof(system.now().format('M'));
            System.debug('month  >>>>>' + month);
            String strRecordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where SobjectType = 'User_SO__c' and Name = 'User'].Id;
            System.debug('strRecordTypeId  >>>>>' + strRecordTypeId);
            String SelectedUserId;
               Id LoggedinUserId=UserInfo.getUserId();
            Test.startTest();
            adjustmentController.fetchLabels(LoggedinUserId);
            adjustmentController.savedata(objs,LoggedinUserId);
             adjustmentController.fetchLabels(u.id);
             adjustmentController.savedata(objs,u.id);
            adjustmentController.savedata(objs,u.id);
            Test.stopTest();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that your [cognitive complexity](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_design.html#cognitivecomplexity) and [cyclomatic complexity](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_design.html#cyclomaticcomplexity) are excessively high. You'd have to write dozens of tests to go through every possible branch. Instead, focus on optimizing your code to reduce the cognitive complexity. Your original code is over 290 lines of code (~250 without debug statements), and I have trivially reduced it to 130  or so lines of code.

Note that you still have some poor practices in here, such as hard-coding record ID values, which won't be portable across all types of orgs. I also haven't bothered to fix any typos or probable glaring logic bugs. In general, your indentation and choice of if statements leads to a lot of code coverage problems as well. I suggest that you start using a tool like Prettier to clean up your code, and ApexPMD to point out other common code quality problems.

Here's my first pass at just reducing cognitive complexity, and thus should result in an immediate rise in code coverage:

```
public class adjustmentController {
    @AuraEnabled public static String thisQuarterLabelval{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public static String secodQuarterLabelval{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public static String thirdQuarterLabelval{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public static String fourthQuarterLabelval{get;set;}
    
    static Map<String, sObjectField> adjustmentFieldMap = new Map<String, sObjectField>{
        '1' => User_SO__c.Week_1_Adjustment__c,
        '2' => User_SO__c.Week_2_Adjustment__c,
        '3' => User_SO__c.Week_3_Adjustment__c,
        '4' => User_SO__c.Week_4_Adjustment__c,
        '5' => User_SO__c.Week_5_Adjustment__c,
        '6' => User_SO__c.Week_6_Adjustment__c
    };

    @AuraEnabled
    public static wrapperAdjustmentLabel fetchLabels(String SelectedUserId){
        Id LoggedinUserId=UserInfo.getUserId();
        String year = ''+system.today().year();
        String month = system.now().format('M'));
        Integer weekcal = integer.valueof(system.now().format('W'));
        Set<Id> UserIdSet= new Map<Id, User>([Select Id from User where IsActive = true and ManagerId =:LoggedinUserId]).keySet();
        wrapperAdjustmentLabel wrap = new wrapperAdjustmentLabel();
        List<Period> currentFiscalYear = [SELECT Id, FiscalYearSettingsId, FiscalYearSettings.Name, StartDate, EndDate, IsForecastPeriod, Number, FullyQualifiedLabel FROM Period Where type = 'Quarter' AND StartDate = THIS_FISCAL_YEAR];
        wrap.thisQuarterLabel= currentFiscalYear[0].FullyQualifiedLabel.right(4)+'-Q1';
        wrap.secondQuarterLabel= currentFiscalYear[1].FullyQualifiedLabel.right(4)+'-Q2';
        wrap.thirdQuarterLabel= currentFiscalYear[2].FullyQualifiedLabel.right(4)+'-Q3';
        wrap.fourthQuarterLabel= currentFiscalYear[3].FullyQualifiedLabel.right(4)+'-Q4';
        Integer QStartdat = currentFiscalYear[0].StartDate.month();
        Integer QEndDate = currentFiscalYear[0].EndDate.month();
        Integer Currentmonth = Integer.valueOf(month);
        wrap.isEnablegrid1=QStartdat<Currentmonth && QEndDate<Currentmonth;
        wrap.isEnablegrid2=currentFiscalYear[1].StartDate.month() < Currentmonth && currentFiscalYear[1].EndDate.month() < Currentmonth;
        wrap.isEnablegrid3=currentFiscalYear[2].StartDate.month() < Currentmonth && currentFiscalYear[2].EndDate.month() < Currentmonth;
        wrap.isEnablegrid4=currentFiscalYear[3].StartDate.month() < Currentmonth && currentFiscalYear[3].EndDate.month() < Currentmonth;
        wrap.isManager=UserIdSet.contains(SelectedUserId);
        thisQuarterLabelval=currentFiscalYear[0].FullyQualifiedLabel;
        secodQuarterLabelval=currentFiscalYear[1].FullyQualifiedLabel;
        thirdQuarterLabelval=currentFiscalYear[2].FullyQualifiedLabel;
        fourthQuarterLabelval=currentFiscalYear[3].FullyQualifiedLabel;
        List<User_SO__c> UserSoList=[select id,Year__c,Month__c,User__c,Week_1_Adjustment__c,Week_2_Adjustment__c,Week_3_Adjustment__c,Week_4_Adjustment__c,Week_5_Adjustment__c,Week_6_Adjustment__c from User_SO__c where Month__c=:month and Year__c=:year and User__c=:SelectedUserId and RecordType.Name='User'];
        String Examplefield;
        FcstJSONClass fcstParentAccWrapObj;
        Date currentdate = Date.today(); 
        FCSTUtil util = new FCSTUtil();
        Integer currentweek = util.currentWeekOfMonth(currentdate);
        String currentmonthweek = ''+currentweek;
        if(!UserSoList.isEmpty()) {
            ExampleField = UserSoList[0].get(adjustmentFieldMap.get(currentmonthweek));    
        }
        if(Examplefield != null){ 
            fcstParentAccWrapObj= (FcstJSONClass) System.JSON.deserialize(Examplefield, FcstJSONClass.class);
            wrap.thisQuarterValue=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q1;
            wrap.secodQuarterValue=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q2;
            wrap.thirdQuarterValue=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q3;
            wrap.fourthQuarterValue=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q4;
        }
        return wrap;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void savedata(wrapperAdjustment wrapper1,String SelectedUserId){
        String Usermass='Success';
        Id LoggedinUserId=UserInfo.getUserId();
        Set<Id> UserIdSet= new Map<Id, User>([Select Id from User where IsActive = true and ManagerId =:LoggedinUserId]).keySet();
        String year = ''+system.today().year();
        String month = system.now().format('M');
        Integer weekcal = integer.valueof(system.now().format('W'));
        String Week1_Adjustment,Week2_Adjustment,Week3_Adjustment,Week4_Adjustment,Week5_Adjustment,Week6_Adjustment;
        fetchLabels(SelectedUserId);
        if(UserIdSet.contains(SelectedUserId)){
            String StartFiscalYear=thisQuarterLabelval.right(4)+'-Q1';
            String EndFiscalYear=fourthQuarterLabelval.right(4)+'-Q4';
            Usermass='Success';
            if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                month='1';
            }
            List<User_SO__c> UserSoList=[select id,Year__c,Month__c,User__c,Week_1_Adjustment__c,Week_2_Adjustment__c,Week_3_Adjustment__c,Week_4_Adjustment__c,Week_5_Adjustment__c,Week_6_Adjustment__c from User_SO__c where Month__c=:month and Year__c=:year and User__c=:SelectedUserId and RecordType.Name='User'];
            String QuarterQ1='0',QuarterQ2='0',QuarterQ3='0',QuarterQ4='0';
            String Examplefield;
            ;
            Date currentdate = Date.today(); 
            FCSTUtil util = new FCSTUtil();
            Integer currentweek = util.currentWeekOfMonth(currentdate);
            String currentmonthweek = ''+currentweek;
            if(!UserSoList.isEmpty()) {
                Examplefield=UserSoList[0].get(adjustmentFieldMap.get(currentmonthweek));
            }
            if(Examplefield != null){ 
                FcstJSONClass fcstParentAccWrapObj=(FcstJSONClass) System.JSON.deserialize(Examplefield, FcstJSONClass.class);
                QuarterQ1=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q1;
                QuarterQ2=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q2;
                QuarterQ3=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q3;
                QuarterQ4=fcstParentAccWrapObj.Quarter[0].Q4;
            }
            
            Map<String, Object> jsonSource = new Map<String, Object> {
                'Fiscal_Year' => StartFiscalYear +' to '+ EndFiscalYear,
                'Year' => Year,
                'Month' => Month__c,
                'Week' => currentmonthweek,
                'UserId' => SelectedUserId,
                'Quarter' => new Map<String, Object> {
                    'Q1' => wrapper1.thisQuarter == null? QuarterQ1: ''+wrapper1.thisQuarter,
                    'Q2' => wrapper1.secodQuarter == null? QuarterQ2:''+wrapper1.secodQuarter,
                    'Q3' => wrapper1.thirdQuarter == null? QuarterQ3: ''+wrapper1.thirdQuarter,
                    'Q4' => wrapper1.fourthQuarter == null? QuarterQ4: ''+wrapper1.fourthQuarter
                }
            };
            String Json=JSON.serialize(jsonSource);
            Week3_Adjustment = json ;
            sobjectField[] weekFieldList = new List<sobjectField>{
                User_SO__c.Week_1_Adjustment__c,
                User_SO__c.Week_2_Adjustment__c,
                User_SO__c.Week_3_Adjustment__c,
                User_SO__c.Week_4_Adjustment__c,
                User_SO__c.Week_5_Adjustment__c,
                User_SO__c.Week_6_Adjustment__c
            };
            for(User_SO__c SO:UserSoList){
                for(Integer i = 0, s = weekFieldList.size(); i < s; i++) {
                    if(currentweek > i) {
                        SO.put(weekFieldList[i], Week3_Adjustment);
                    }
                }                
            }
            update UserSoList;
        } else {
            Usermass='You are not authorised Person'; 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm questioning a lot of the logic here, but that's not the point of this answer. I am simply stating that having too many branching paths makes it harder to get code coverage, so you should focus on reducing the complexity as much as possible. As you continue to fix the code, study this code above to see how we can fix a lot of inefficiency by reducing redundant logic, leveraging lists and maps when possible, avoiding using variables that are literally used just once, and so on. There's a lot of techniques you can leverage.

Comment: They're probably roughly synonymous in most scenarios, but I believe you meant cyclomatic complexity as it relates to coverage. Never mind, I guess PMD uses that terminology.

Comment: @AdrianLarson No, you're right, I meant to use cyclomatic complexity, though it hardly matters in this case; both cognitive and cyclomatic complexity rules were excessively broken in the original code.

Comment: True that! Would have been an interesting code review to see someone try to explain what any of this code does.

Comment: Thanku for your help